# How to write below condition in Helm chart syntax in a job.yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have to write this condition in helm chart syntax in job.yaml file so that imagePullSecrets get's executed only when the condition is satisfied.

Condition is
**when: (network.docker.username | default('', true) | trim != '') and (network.docker.password | default('', true) | trim != '')**

To write above condition below this code:
**imagePullSecrets:
- name: "{{ $.Values.image.pullSecret }}"**

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, Docker username & password should come from Secrets. Here's the Sample helm code to use if in yaml file:

```
imagePullSecrets: 
{{ if and (ne $.Values.network.docker.password '') (ne $.Values.network.docker.username '') }}
- name: "{{ $.Values.image.pullSecret }}"
{{ end }}
```

And values.yaml should have:

```
network:
  docker:
    username: your-uname
    password: your-pwd
```